# MDX function to find if a Member IsMemberOf a set

Tags: ssas, mdx

This feels like a really basic question, because it's a really basic function I'm looking for.

I know you can do this:

```
([Dimension].CurrentMember IS [Dimension].[AParticularMember])
```

and you get a logical 1 or 0 as the function value.

But how do you do this kind of thing, without concatenating IS functions in a whole lot of ugly ORs:

```
([Dimension].CurrentMember ISAMEMBEROF 
     {[Dimension].[AMember],[Dimension].[AnotherMember],[Dimension].[YetAnotherMember]}
)
```

?

This is really basic set operations, in one dimension only, but I just can't find the damn function that does it.  I tried this:

```
NOT(ISEMPTY(INTERSECT([Dimension].CurrentMember,
{[Dimension].[AMember],[Dimension].[AnotherMember],[Dimension].[YetAnotherMember]})))
```

but it returned True for every dimension member.  I'm guessing this is because what is going into the ISEMPTY function is not the dimension member, but the tuple

```
([Dimension].CurrentMember,[AnotherDimension].DefaultMember,  
[YetAnotherDimension].DefaultMember,... ,Measures.DefaultMember)
```

does the kind of function I'm looking for exist in MDX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close:

```
INTERSECT([Dimension].CurrentMember,
{[Dimension].[AMember],[Dimension].[AnotherMember],[Dimension].[YetAnotherMember]}).Count > 0
```