# Implementing IN /LIKE in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a dimension called `[Band]` and it can have several different values:

```
[Band].&[A]&[Under $400]
[Band].&[B]&[$400 - $1,000]
[Band].&[C]&[$1,000 - $2,500]
[Band].&[D]&[$2,500 - $3,500]
...
```

I'm trying to write a query where I can cut by a sublist of these values.

Here's the query that is not working because the `.isin` function doesn't exist in MDX, but you'll see what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measure A], [Measure B]} ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY {([Band].isin(['Under $400', '$400 - $1,000']).ALLMEMBERS)} --fail on .isin(
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ({[Foo].&[Bar]}) ON COLUMNS 
  FROM
    [CUBE]
)
```

Now, here's a query that is working, but it only gives me one `[Band]` value:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measure A], [Measure B]} ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY {([Band].&[A]&[Under $400])}
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ({[Foo].&[Bar]}) ON COLUMNS 
  FROM
    [CUBE]
)
```

This returns a valid result of:

```
              Measure A    Measure B
Under $400    1795.67%     58.48%
```

But I'd like to see results where it returns the aggregated values of multiple `[Band]` dimension values. How can this be done in MDX?

As you can probably tell I've never used MDX before, but as I search on this issue I see things like [taking the intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585120/mdx-function-to-find-if-a-member-ismemberof-a-set), or using [ChildrenSet](https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/analyze-and-visualize/calculated-members/mdx-function-reference/childrenset). But it doesn't seem very intuitive.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So following is a list of how IsIn funcationality can be implemented in MDX

1)you want to filter using in clause and show the members too.
In this example I want to see the internet sales for bikes and clothing category from adventurewroks sample db

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
{[Product].[Category].&[1]
,[Product].[Category].&[3]}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

2)I want to filter by the IN clause but dont want to show the members
In this example I want to see yearly the internet sales for bikes and clothing category from adventurewroks sample db. The result is to be broken by years.

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
non empty 
[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
where 
{[Product].[Category].&[1]
,[Product].[Category].&[2]}
```

Result

[image]

You achive the same by using subquery

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
non empty 
[Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year]
on rows 
from 
(select {[Product].[Category].&[1],[Product].[Category].&[2]} on 0 from [Adventure Works])
```

Result

[image]

3)When you want to implement the IN clause based on name 
In this example I want to see the internet sales for bikes and clothing category from adventurewroks sample db, but in this case I am using the caption

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
filter(
[Product].[Category].[Category],
[Product].[Category].currentmember.name='Bikes' or [Product].[Category].currentmember.name='Clothing'
)
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result :

[image]

4) When you implement IN clause based on name and your condition is looking for a particular text (Like Clause )
In this example I want to see the internet sales for bikes and clothing category from adventurewroks sample db, but in this case I am searching the the caption name for a piece of string.

```
select 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
on columns,
FILTER([Product].[Category].[Category],
Instr([Product].[Category].currentmember.name, 'Bik') > 0
or 
Instr([Product].[Category].currentmember.name, 'oth') > 0
)
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

figured it out I think

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measure A], [Measure B]} ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY {[Band].[Under $400], [Band].[$1,000 - $2,500]}
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ({[Foo].&[Bar]}) ON COLUMNS 
  FROM
    [CUBE]
)
```

Comment: if you want to do multiple dimensions this way it becomes `{([dim A]).ALLMEMBERS} * {[Band].[Under $400], [Band].[$1,000 - $2,500]}`